# How to make Simplify output expressions only with certain Jacobi elliptic functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Consider

```
Psi0 = EllipticK[k^2] - p;
x[t_] := k (JacobiDN[Psi0, k^2] (JacobiCN[Psi0, k^2] - JacobiCN[Psi0+t/k, k^2]) + JacobiSN[Psi0, k^2] * (t/k + JacobiEpsilon[Psi0, k^2] - JacobiEpsilon[Psi0+t/k, k^2]));

FullSimplify[x[2 k p]] (* = k*(-2*(-1 + k^2)*JacobiND[p, k^2]*JacobiSD[p, k^2] + 2*JacobiCD[p, k^2]*(p - JacobiEpsilon[p, k^2] + k^2*JacobiCD[p, k^2]*JacobiSN[p,k^2])) *)
```

Is there a way to have FullSimplify to output expressions involving Jacobi elliptic functions only with three functions `JacobiSN`, `JacobiCN`, and `JacobiDN`? For example, `FullSimplify[x[2 k p]]` has `JacobiSD` and `JacobiCD` in its output.

My second question is about `FullSimplify[x[t]]`. I had to interrupt it after running for two hours on my system without giving any result. Is this normal? my equation does not seem to be that complex for it to get stuck (I am using Wolfram Language 13.2).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I don't know much about Jacobi functions, so are you sure your expression can be written only with those three functions? Furthermore, are there any assumptions about `p` and `k` (real, positive etc.)? For example: `FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[x[2 k p]]]` returns an expression with `JacobiCN`, `JacobiDN`, `JacobiSN` but also `JacobiEpsilon` ...

Comment: The last formula in the properties section of the documentation on JacobiEpsilon shows that the `JacobiEpsilon` function can be replaced by `JacobiZN` and a ratio of elliptic functions. Specifically, it shows that `JacobiZN` can be written as $$\mathcal{E}(u|m)-\frac{u
   E(m)}{K(m)}$$

Comment: @Domen Thanks, your suggestion works. I wanted only the twelve `Jacobi**` functions to be represented with `JacobiSN`, `JacobiCN`, and `JacobiDN`, which is possible. For example, `FullSimplify[JacobiCN[p, m] * JacobiNS[p, m] - JacobiCS[p, m]] (* = 0*)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Psi0 = EllipticK[k^2] - p;
x[t_] := k (JacobiDN[Psi0, 
       k^2] (JacobiCN[Psi0, k^2] - JacobiCN[Psi0 + t/k, k^2]) + 
     JacobiSN[Psi0, 
       k^2]*(t/k + JacobiEpsilon[Psi0, k^2] - 
        JacobiEpsilon[Psi0 + t/k, k^2]));
```

As Domen pointed out in his comment, [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html) helps in this case.

```
FullSimplify[x[2 k p] // FunctionExpand]

(* 2 k ((JacobiCN[p, k^2] (p - JacobiEpsilon[p, k^2]))/JacobiDN[p, k^2] + 
   JacobiSN[p, k^2]) *)
```

In general, the [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) option is used in [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) or [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) to penalize undesired expressions.

```
cf[e_] := 100 (Count[e, _JacobiCD, {0, Infinity}] +
     Count[e, _JacobiSD, {0, Infinity}]) + LeafCount[e]

FullSimplify[x[2 k p], ComplexityFunction -> cf]

(* 2 k ((JacobiCN[p, k^2] (p - JacobiEpsilon[p, k^2]))/JacobiDN[p, k^2] + 
   JacobiSN[p, k^2]) *)
```

However, this doesn't work in this case to eliminate the [`JacobiEpsilon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JacobiEpsilon.html)

```
cf2[e_] := 100 (Count[e, _JacobiCD, {0, Infinity}] +
     Count[e, _JacobiSD, {0, Infinity}] +
     Count[e, _JacobiEpsilon, {0, Infinity}]) + LeafCount[e]

FullSimplify[x[2 k p], ComplexityFunction -> cf2]

(* 2 k ((JacobiCN[p, k^2] (p - JacobiEpsilon[p, k^2]))/JacobiDN[p, k^2] + 
   JacobiSN[p, k^2]) *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply no at current state of affairs.
The reference e.g. JacobiSN says:  Only simple simplfications are implemented.

So,  stearing the course clear of undesireable functions, does not work for elliptics as it does e,g, for trigs

```
Assuming[  x \[Element] Reals, 
  FullSimplify[ Tan[x]^2, 
   ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
     100000 Count[#, _Sec | _Tan , \[Infinity]] - 
    1000000 Count[#, _Exp, \[Infinity]] &)]]

-((-1+E^(2 I x))^2/(1+E^(2 I x))^2)


FullSimplify[1-JacobiDN[x,m]^2, 
 ComplexityFunction->(LeafCount[#]+ 10000 Count[#,JacobiDN[_,_]|JacobiCN[_,_],oo]&) ]]

1-JacobiDN[x,m]^2
```

My simple workaraound:

Replace all  JacobiSN, -CN etc of the same modulus m by their geometric names
sn[x], cn[y] etc and use the standard simplification replacement list for a group of equal modulus m functions with differnet arguments x,y

```
 reducetosnList= *
{cn[x_]^k?Positive:> (1-sn[x]^2) * cn[x]^(k-2), 
dn[x_]^k?Positive:> (1-m sn[x]^2) * dn[x]^(k-2), 
cn[x_]^k?Neagative:> 1/(1-sn[x]^2) * cn[x]^(k+2), 
dn[x_]^k?Negative:> 1/(1-m sn[x]^2)  *  dn[x]^(k+2)., 
 "convert list of all others to sn,cn dn" ...}
```

The current implementation of the Jacobi elliptic functions in vs 13 suffers from an extensive overhead of automatic checks  for possible zeros or periods in EllipticK. I came over this problem, when I realized, that the JacobiAmplitude for modulus m>1 no longer is a real continous periodic function as it was in vs 11,  describing the low energy, oscillatory solutions of the pendulum equation.

Nearly each time I tried via ComplexPlot to analyze my problems, Windows shuts down the kernel with error 000005, a privilege violation  or out of memory event.

As an experienced conspiracy theorist one may hypothesize, that there exist code traps from elliptic cryptography. As an experienced checker of students results of coding MMA procedures, a simple table transfer error is the more probable scenario. I did not analyze the numeric code basis for FORTRAN as the numeerical standard.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. Bob's answer worked for me, since in this instance, all I wanted was for Simply not to change my original functions. Nevertheless your answer spared me from asking a second question about simplifying more general Elliptic expressions. Similar to your experience with `ComplexPlot`, I get kernel shutdowns left and right when using FindRoot with the Jacobi functions. Not having your expertise though, I am at the mercy of the developers to fix these issues in future updates.

Comment: FYI, regarding the issue you mentioned for JacobiAmplitude, the "Possible Issues" part of the documentation for JacobiAmplitude gives another definition for the function that says it works "For physical applications where a continuous version is desired for $m>1$."

Comment: I know,because the many inequivalent forms, that are countable finite,  arise from am'=dn and  dn( x,| 1/k^2]~ cn[x | k],   and the integral of cn . But that does not explain the switching  at vs 11 from the trivial periodic integral over cn along the real line to a complicated path model of integration encircling one imaginary pole per period.  From now on, WOLFRAMS JacobiAM will count the periods of ocillations like a pendulum clock  :.)